# Why does the 'tsc' command not work in git bash terminal and does work in command promt

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, terminal, git-bash

I have installed TypeScript globally on my machine but i cannot use it in git bash terminal.

The error that i get when I execute `tsc -v` is:

> C:\Users\itupe\AppData\Roaming\npm/node: line 8:
> C:\Users\itupe\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: No such file or directory

The thing is when I run the command in command prompt everything is fine.

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening? I found a lot of information about paths and this like that on the internet but I cannot figure it out how this things work together.

Answer (score 0):

I think that git bash is missing the path for npm.

check your PATH variable in Git Bash using:

```bash
echo $PATH
```

see if the directory `C:\Users\itupe\AppData\Roaming\npm` is included in the PATH.

make sure that Git Bash is using the same version of Node.js that command prompt is using.

```bash
node -v
```

check if the command prompt using the same version of node js as git bash.

Comment: I checked the path and it seems to be there. I have got this:

VS Code/bin:/c/Users/itupe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/itupe/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Also, the node version is the same for all my terminals.